# Error: The ntoreturn find command parameter is not supported when FCV >= 5.1

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am using Robo 3T 1.4.3 for mongodb and mongodb version is 6.0.3.
Getting below error when getting more than 50 records in Robo 3T.
So plz. suggest to resolve the issue..

**"Failed to load documents.**

**Error:**
**The ntoreturn find command parameter is not supported when FCV >= 5.1"**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use this command to run in Robo 3t:

db.adminCommand({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "5.0",}).

This works fine for me.

reference: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1891

Answer (score 3):

From [Robo 3T's site](https://robomongo.org/):

> Why is work on Robo 3T being halted?

> Robo 3T is deeply based on the Mongo shell client. This older client has been deprecated in MongoDB 5.0 and is not expected to be maintained in the future. The new Mongosh client is a Node-based tool and is not compatible with the current Robo 3T architecture. Studio 3T took the decision to create a free edition of their tool suite to replace Robo 3T which matched the functionality and would be able to track future MongoDB developments. You can read more about this on the [Robo 3T blog](https://blog.robomongo.org/studio3t-free/).

Seemingly, Robo 3T has been deprecated and will not support for your MongoDB v6.0 version. You should migrate to [Studio 3T for free](https://studio3t.com/download-studio3t-free) as they suggest.

Comment: Time to fork it?